# Attempting to install Oauth on php 8.0 Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, oauth

I have tried a ton of things at this point, but I'm getting this error when I try and run

```
sudo yum install php-pecl-oauth
```

It's telling me that I'm missing php(api) and php(zend-abi)? I don't know what to install to fix it. What exactly does this mean (I have tried installing every variation of php-common in the list and available form amazon packages) and what should I install to fix it?

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-oauth-1.2.3-8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20100412-64
           Installed: php-common-8.0.20-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.0-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.2-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.6-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.8-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.13-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.16-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.18-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(api) = 20200930-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-oauth-1.2.3-8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Installed: php-common-8.0.20-1.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.0-2.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.2-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.6-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.8-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.13-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.16-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
           Available: php-common-8.0.18-1.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2extra-php8.0)
               php(zend-abi) = 20200930-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Do yourself a favor, ditch pecl's oauth, and use the appropriate package from https://thephpleague.com/#packages.

Comment: help me understand what you mean. I'm using an sdk that is demanding Oauth. I just looked up how to get it and landed here. What is the better way of getting Oauth? Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: What SDK are you using? Does it specifically require the PECL extension? If it does, have you tried just `pecl install oauth`?

Comment: I'm running amazon linux 2 and I'm trying to run an SP-API integration. It was throwing 500s and saying Oauth not found, and I just searched and ended up in PECL as a way to get Oauth. I really don't know enough about it though, I'm not super educated on all these packages or any of it. I did just update to php 8.0 though (from 7.4) and I don't even know if that is related.

Comment: The sdk is https://github.com/amazon-php/sp-api-sdk. I don't think it specifically needs PECL, I just landed there from searching how to get Oauth installed.

Comment: and yeah, when I run `pecl install oauth`, it says it is already installed.

Comment: That package comes *with* its own OAuth implementation already; https://github.com/amazon-php/sp-api-sdk/blob/22894128337f861e5095b6dd3e48c361453daf86/src/AmazonPHP/SellingPartner/OAuth.php. You don't need to install anything.

Comment: Well I'm an idiot. Thanks. it's a matter of just including that part of the package files in my code then? I guess I got bombarded by all the mess that was updating php, I was convinced it was a package issue. Thanks so much

Comment: Also thanks for your reference to thephpleague, I'll hang onto that for the future.